# Default reset password email not sent via Appcelerator backend, nor emails with a template, only email configuration changes are sent

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium

When I execute the following code,

```
Cloud.Users.requestResetPassword({
                email: myUsersEmailAddress
            }, function (e) {
                if (e.success) {
                    Ti.API.info('Success: Reset Request Sent ' +      JSON.stringify(e));
                } else {
                    Ti.API.error('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message)    || JSON.stringify(e)));
                }
            });
```

I should receive an email to reset my password, as seen in the documentation:

> GET users/request_reset_password.json Sends an email to a user
>   containing a link to recover a lost password. You can use the default
>   email template provided by ACS, or specify a custom email template
>   that you have created. When using a custom email template, the email
>   must contain a properly formatted URL, as explained in the template
>   method parameter documentation below.

When the alert pops up, I can see that there was a match and that an email should have been sent.

However, I do not receive an email, nor do I see anything in the logs of my email backend (which does receive an email when I adapt my email configuration on the appc backend, thus my email is correctly configured)

I don't have any email templates configured, but according to the documentation it should use appc's default reset password email.

Does anyone has an idea about what I am doing wrong, or does this indicate an issue with appc's documentation or backend?

UPDATE: I have another function which sends email using a self-defined email template. When I invoke this function, i receive the following event(between the {}):
[INFO] :   Deactivation email sent. {"success":true,"error":false,"meta":{"status":"ok","code":200,"method_name":"emailFromTemplate"}}

However, nothing is seen on our smtp backend. The only things we do see (and which we receive in our mailbox) are the emails which are sent when you adapt your email configuration settings in Appcelerator's backend, eg.

> Subject: Appcelerator Cloud Services SMTP Test
>   Appcelerator Logo Hi Peter,
>   Your SMTP settings have been updated successfully!
>   Onward,
>   The Appcelerator Platform Team

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a configuration issue, which could only be discovered by doing some curl calls against the api. So a good advice, test your config with curl too, and don't rely on the emails which are sent after you made a configuration change!